# Changing directory doesn't persist in php script called by apache

Tags: php, apache, shell-exec

I'm trying to build a script that makes some changes on my server, that I can call by visiting a webpage.

However, I've run into a number of difficulties regarding the permissions of the apache user, who tries to run the shell commands inside my php script.  Depending on your server, the user may be wwwrun or wwwdata.

For example, I would like to change directory to `../subdomains/$url/httpdocs/`, but if I run a subsequent `pwd`, I haven't changed directory.  I can list the other directory, but the permissions on the folders prevent me from making most changes.

I can't just go in to the server manually and chmod the folders, though, because the folders are supposed to be automatically generated by the system just before I go in to make the other changes.

At first, I tried editing /etc/sudoers, which worked for the executables on my machine that I actually know the location of.  However, despite all my searches, I can't find the location of BaSH built in executables, like cd.  But, I feel like this is a red herring.  It would probably be bad for security to add those functions to my sudoers file.

Maybe apache suEXEC is the way to go. But I'm not very advanced in my server administration travels, and I haven't found an adequate guide for someone of my skill levels to install and set it up.

I've also attempted to cook up a shell script, that I could call from the first php script, but I am struggling with getting that to work at all.  I will stay with it, but I feel like I can and should be able to get the original file to work.

Sorry for the wall of text.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I use to create individual directories for each registered user of a dating site I had, so that after they uploaded images and it went through all the necessary processing and security it would dump it into a file with that users id. That way instead of having to search thousands of images i only had to search a small directory based on the user_id. This is how i did it. Maybe it will help you.

```
    //path has to already exist with 773 perm
    $path = 'path/to/dir';

    //name of new dir, I use user ids for this
        $dirname = '0123456789';

    //create folder for user if one doesn't exist
    //for this to work; had to edit /etc/sudoer with: sudo visudo -s command
    //added: www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    $thisdir = getcwd();
    $dir = $thisdir ."/".$path."/".$dirname;

    if(!is_dir($dir)){

            mkdir($dir, 0731);

            //required to change dir perm to 755
            $old = umask(0);
            chmod($dir, 0731);
            umask($old);

    }
```

Comment: I think that a lot of the difficulty I am having is that I am trying to go into a directory above the web root.